# c# VS 17.7.4 TabControl bkg color pallette is blank in (Collection)

Tags: visual-studio, tabcontrol, backcolor

I can change the background color of the tab panels (TabControl) via the Properties Window, but not when I try it via the (Collection) editor.  I click on the BackColor Down Button (to the right) and I get an empty grey square where I would normally get my color options (Custom, Webb, System).

I ran the same test on a new project on a clean form and it works (change BackColor in Collection editor).  I don't see why my TabControl would be any different on the software I am working on.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.